# Why saving to parquet file with over 10000 columns lead to JaninoRuntimeException?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have this code that generates a random df and writes it to disk as parquet file in spark 2.1. This runs into problem when the number of columns goes to 10000 but for 10000 it seems work fine.

In the 100000 columns case spark just prints a bunch of code on the screen and throws an error as below.

How can i write this to parquet without the error?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,IntegerType,DoubleType}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import scala.util.Random
import scala.math

val nRows = 10000
val nCols = 100000
val rD = sc.parallelize(0 to nRows-1).map { _ => Row.fromSeq(Seq.fill(nCols)(math.ceil(1000*Random.nextDouble()))) }

val schema = StructType((0 to nCols-1).map { i => StructField("C" + i, DoubleType, true) } )
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rD, schema)
df.select("*").write.format("parquet").save("df.parquet")  

/* 379357 */   private void apply_22702(InternalRow i) {
/* 379358 */
/* 379359 */
/* 379360 */     boolean isNull90808 = i.isNullAt(90808);
/* 379361 */     double value90808 = isNull90808 ? -1.0 :  (i.getDouble(90808));
/* 379362 */     if (isNull90808) {
/* 379363 */       rowWriter.setNullAt(90808);
/* 379364 */     } else { 
/* 379365 */       rowWriter.write(90808, value90808);
/* 379366 */     }
/* 379367 */
/* 379368 */
/* 379369 */     boolean isNull90809 = i.isNullAt(90809);  
/* 379370 */     double value90809 = isNull90809 ? -1.0 : (i.getDouble(90809));
/* 379371 */     if (isNull90809) {
/* 379372 */       rowWriter.setNullAt(90809);
/* 379373 */     } else {
/* 379374 */       rowWriter.write(90809, value90809);
/* 379375 */     }
/* 379376 */
/* 379377 */
/* 379378 */     boolean isNull90810 = i.isNullAt(90810);
/* 379379 */     double value90810 = isNull90810 ? -1.0 : (i.getDouble(90810)); 
/* 379380 */     if (isNull90810) {
/* 379381 */       rowWriter.setNullAt(90810);
/* 379382 */     } else {
/* 379383 */       rowWriter.write(90810, value90810);
/* 379384 */     }
/* 379385 */
.
.
.
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:998)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:995)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: Constant pool for class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection has grown past JVM limit of 0xFFFF
    at org.codehaus.janino.util.ClassFile.addToConstantPool(ClassFile.java:499)
    at org.codehaus.janino.util.ClassFile.addConstantIntegerInfo(ClassFile.java:395)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.addConstantIntegerInfo(UnitCompiler.java:11137)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.pushConstant(UnitCompiler.java:9681)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGet2(UnitCompiler.java:4911)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$7700(UnitCompiler.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$12.visitIntegerLiteral(UnitCompiler.java:3776)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$12.visitIntegerLiteral(UnitCompiler.java:3762)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$IntegerLiteral.accept(Java.java:4635)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGet(UnitCompiler.java:3762)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.fakeCompile(UnitCompiler.java:3128)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGetValue(UnitCompiler.java:4927)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGet2(UnitCompiler.java:4526)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$7500(UnitCompiler.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$12.visitMethodInvocation(UnitCompiler.java:3774)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$12.visitMethodInvocation(UnitCompiler.java:3762)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$MethodInvocation.accept(Java.java:4328)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGet(UnitCompiler.java:3762)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGetValue(UnitCompiler.java:4933)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:2330)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$2600(UnitCompiler.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$6.visitLocalVariableDeclarationStatement(UnitCompiler.java:1386)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$6.visitLocalVariableDeclarationStatement(UnitCompiler.java:1370)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$LocalVariableDeclarationStatement.accept(Java.java:2974)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:1370)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileStatements(UnitCompiler.java:1450)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:2811)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileDeclaredMethods(UnitCompiler.java:1262)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileDeclaredMethods(UnitCompiler.java:1234)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:538)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:890)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:894)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$600(UnitCompiler.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$2.visitMemberClassDeclaration(UnitCompiler.java:377)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$2.visitMemberClassDeclaration(UnitCompiler.java:369)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$MemberClassDeclaration.accept(Java.java:1128)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:369)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileDeclaredMemberTypes(UnitCompiler.java:1209)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:420)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$400(UnitCompiler.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$2.visitPackageMemberClassDeclaration(UnitCompiler.java:374)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$2.visitPackageMemberClassDeclaration(UnitCompiler.java:369)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$AbstractPackageMemberClassDeclaration.accept(Java.java:1309)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:369)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileUnit(UnitCompiler.java:345)
    at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.compileToClassLoader(SimpleCompiler.java:396)
    at org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.compileToClass(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:311)
    at org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.cook(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:196)
    at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.Cookable.cook(Cookable.java:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:935)
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like one of those nasty issues with codegen going beyond 64k-method limit (as reported in [SPARK-18492](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18492) and [SPARK-16845](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16845)).

You may want to check out one of the nightly 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT version from [the Nightly Packages and Artifacts](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html#nightly-packages-and-artifacts) and see if that may solve your issue in the future (when the version will be released).

Comment: 2.2.0 has since been released